# Multiple geofences with same location coordinates but different radius

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, geofencing

I am working on an application where proximity based events are triggered depending of levels of proximity(NEAR, INTERMEDIATE,FAR). Is it possible to monitor multiple geofences with same location coordinates but different radius? I know ranging could be done with BLE beacons but I need to probably work in range of 500 mtrs and above.

Is there any other way of doing this.

Platforms - Android iOS both

Comment: I have gone through android geofences and geofire library. Geofire doesn't provide this feature.

Comment: And what prevents you from adding multiple Geofences with the same coordinates and different Radius? Did you read Geofences documentation?

Comment: I agree that for each Geofence it should be possible to specify a different radius for each event (dwell, enter and exit), so I could separate events according to the radius using the same requestId and without consuming the limited amount of geofences.